# Creating an AI for BlackJack

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, blackjack

I am trying to make a Blackjack game! I am successful with player interaction! However, I decided to step it up and do some AI so I can play against AI, and have more of a battle, so to speak.

My main issue though, is I've sat here for about an hour or so thinking of how AI works and how I could use it, and I've not been able to think of anything that could work. So I was wondering if anyone had any ideas, or was able to guide me in a direction.

I do not have any code for a start of an AI, since I can't think of how to start one or work with one. That is why I'm hoping for some kind of direction.

Now I will post my classes that I think is all relevant. I did leave out the Game class. The Game Class is just for validation and checking Cards and all that amazing stuff.

Class Card:

```
public class Card{
private int rank, suit;

private String[] suitNames = new String[]{ "H", "C", "S", "D" };
private String[] rankNumber = new String[]{ "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };
private int[] points = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10};

Card(int suitIndex, int rankIndex){
    rank = rankIndex;
    suit = suitIndex;
}

public @Override String toString(){
    return rankNumber[rank]+suitNames[suit]; 
}

public int getRank(){
    return rank;
}

public int getSuit(){
    return suit;
}

public String getSuitName(){
    return suitNames[suit];
}

public String getRankName(){
    return rankNumber[rank];
}

public int getPoints(){
     return points[rank];
}

public ImageIcon ImageOfCard() throws Exception{
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("/StandardDeck/GameCards/"+getRankName() + getSuitName()+".png");
    return icon;
}
}
```

Class BlackJack (Game with all the stuff) Yes I did use Java GUI just to work on it.

```
public class BlackJack extends JFrame {
Game game;
Deck deck;
Card cards;
Player player;
Dealer dealer;
JLabel[] playerCardSlots;
JLabel[] dealerCardSlots;

public BlackJack() {
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your name");
    deck = new Deck(4);
    game = new Game();
    player = new Player(name);
    dealer = new Dealer(deck);

    initComponents();
    SetButtons(false);
    playerCardSlots = new JLabel[]{Player1Card1, Player1Card2, Player1Card3, Player1Card4, Player1Card5};
    dealerCardSlots = new JLabel[]{DealerCard1, DealerCard2, DealerCard3, DealerCard4, DealerCard5};
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    Player1Card1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Player1Card2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Player1Card3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Player1Card4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Player1Card5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Player1Name = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    HitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    StandButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    PointsLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    DealButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    DealerCard1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    DealerCard2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    DealerCard3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    DealerCard4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    DealerCard5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    DealerPointsLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    DealerLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Player1Name.setText("Player 1 Name");

    HitButton.setText("Hit");
    HitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            HitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    StandButton.setText("Stand");
    StandButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            StandButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    PointsLabel.setText("points");

    DealButton.setText("Deal");
    DealButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            DealButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    DealerPointsLabel.setText("points");

    DealerLabel.setText("Dealer");

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(54, 54, 54)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .add(76, 76, 76)
                            .add(Player1Name)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, 104, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                .add(DealerPointsLabel)
                                .add(PointsLabel))
                            .add(128, 128, 128)))
                    .add(DealButton))
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                        .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .add(Player1Card1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                            .add(Player1Card2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                            .add(Player1Card3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                            .add(Player1Card4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .add(12, 12, 12)
                            .add(Player1Card5, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                                .add(DealerLabel)
                                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .add(DealerCard1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                                    .add(DealerCard2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .add(12, 12, 12)
                                    .add(DealerCard3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                            .add(DealerCard4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .add(DealerCard5, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                        .add(HitButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .add(StandButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(13, 13, 13)
            .add(DealerLabel)
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                .add(HitButton)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(DealerCard1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 60, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(DealerCard2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(DealerCard3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(DealerCard4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(DealerCard5, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(StandButton)
                .add(DealerPointsLabel))
            .add(4, 4, 4)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(PointsLabel)
                .add(DealButton))
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(Player1Card1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(Player1Card2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(Player1Card3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(Player1Card4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(Player1Card5, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
            .add(Player1Name)
            .addContainerGap(29, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void HitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    PlayerHit();
}                                         

private void StandButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    PlayerStand();
}                                           

private void DealButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    ResetGame();
}                                          

public void SetName(){
    Player1Name.setText(player.getName());
}

public void DealCards(){
    player.AddCard(deck.DrawCard());
    dealer.AddCard(deck.DrawCard());
    player.AddCard(deck.DrawCard());
    dealer.AddCard(deck.DrawCard());
    ShowCards(player, player.CountCards());
    ShowCards(dealer, 1);

    SetButtons(true);
}

public void DealerHit(){
    dealer.AddCard(deck.DrawCard());
}

public void DealerStand(){
    dealer.PlayerStand();
}

public void PlayerHit(){
    player.AddCard(deck.DrawCard());
    ShowCards(player, player.CountCards());
}
public void PlayerStand(){
    player.PlayerStand();
    SetButtons(false);
    dealer.PlayerTurn();
}

public void ShowCards(Player person, int cards){
    if(!person.getName().equals("Dealer")){
        for(int i = 0; i < cards; i++){
            playerCardSlots[i].setText(person.getCard(i).toString());
        }

        int points = game.CardTotal(person);
        if(game.PlayerBust(points)){
            PointsLabel.setText("BUST!");
            SetButtons(false);
        }
        else{
            PointsLabel.setText(points+"");
        }

        if(game.CardDraw(person)){
            PointsLabel.setText("5 Card Draw!");
            SetButtons(false);
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < cards; i++){
            dealerCardSlots[i].setText(person.getCard(i).toString());
        }

        int points = game.CardTotal(person, cards);

        if(game.PlayerBust(points)){
            DealerPointsLabel.setText("BUST!");
            SetButtons(false);
        }
        else{
            DealerPointsLabel.setText(points+"");
        }

        if(game.CardDraw(person)){
            DealerPointsLabel.setText("5 Card Draw!");
            SetButtons(false);
        }

        if(points >= 17){

        }
    }
}

public void SetButtons(boolean enabled){
        HitButton.setEnabled(enabled);
        StandButton.setEnabled(enabled);
}

public void ResetGame(){
    for(JLabel label : playerCardSlots){
        label.setText("");
    }
    for(JLabel label : dealerCardSlots){
        label.setText("");
    }

    player.ClearCards();
    dealer.ClearCards();

    deck = new Deck(4);
    DealCards();
    SetName();

    player.PlayerTurn();
    dealer.PlayerStand();
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Variables">
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton DealButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel DealerCard1;
private javax.swing.JLabel DealerCard2;
private javax.swing.JLabel DealerCard3;
private javax.swing.JLabel DealerCard4;
private javax.swing.JLabel DealerCard5;
private javax.swing.JLabel DealerLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel DealerPointsLabel;
private javax.swing.JButton HitButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel Player1Card1;
private javax.swing.JLabel Player1Card2;
private javax.swing.JLabel Player1Card3;
private javax.swing.JLabel Player1Card4;
private javax.swing.JLabel Player1Card5;
private javax.swing.JLabel Player1Name;
private javax.swing.JLabel PointsLabel;
private javax.swing.JButton StandButton;
// End of variables declaration                   
//</editor-fold>
}
```

Class Player:

```
 public class Player{
 private String playerName;
 private ArrayList<Card> playerCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
 private boolean turn = false;

Player(String name){
    playerName = name;
}

public Card getCard(int index){
    return playerCards.get(index);
}

public void AddCard(Card card){
    playerCards.add(card);
}

public void ClearCards(){
    playerCards.clear();
}

public int CountCards(){
    return playerCards.size();
}

public String getName(){
    return playerName;
}

public void PlayerStand(){
    turn = false;
}

public void PlayerTurn(){
    turn = true;
}

public boolean getTurn(){
    return turn;
}

}
```

Comment: `while(total < 17) hit();` might do alright.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no AI to blackjack. The house has a fixed algorithm and there's a fixed algorithm for player's best game.

Comment: The rules for a "dealer" are super-simple. There is no intelligence at all. On 17 or higher the dealer must stay. On 16 or lower he must hit. You could start with a dealer AI and then extend it to make a player AI.

Comment: It's been done: search for "blackjack" here: http://okmij.org/ftp/Algorithms.html

Comment: No one will read all that code.

Comment: Another option is to allow the dealer to cheat :-) That's how games make things more difficult!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: Blackjack is indeed interesting from a geeks viewpoint.

As someone has commented: The bank uses a fixed algorithm for all it's actions. These actions are (usually? or always? Find out your self.) only depending on the banks hand. Implement that first.

For the player you should definitively implement what blackjack players call "Basic Strategy". I guess a google search will give you lots of hits.

**Now here is what I would have studied**:
Having the bank fixed strategy and the players "basic strategy" implemented, you can start doing Monte Carlo simulations to find the expectation of the game. Try to get the MC simulation code as fast as possible since, you probably want to do a lot of MC simulations.

Now try to slightly modify the deck. Try for example to remove all 5s from the deck. Then do the same MC simulation, and see if this alters the expectation. Would you like to play BJ with a deck without 5s?

Now, modify the deck again. Try to remove half of all the 10s in the deck (That's half of *all* cards with the value 10). How does that alter the players expectation?

Now modify the deck again. Try to remove half of the non-10 values cards. How does that affect the expectation?

Keep on modifying the deck a tiny bit, and try to get an understanding of how a small bias in the distribution of remaining cards affect the expectation. You should use this understanding to adjust the stake of the game. The strategy is hence not the hit/stand action, but rather the money management based on the distribution bias in the remaining deck in the shoe. Keep hitting/standing decisions based on "basic strategy"!

**Now further steps:**
Maybe you can train a neural net (or some other estimating algorithm) to estimate the expectation of the game based on the known remaining cards in the deck? (You have to keep track of the cards remaining in the shoe.) Maybe you can even connect the MC simulation tool to the training algorithm to give you a kind of reinforcement learning algorithm. This is actually starting to sound like real geek fun! Or maybe you can get the MC-simulator to be so fast that get a good answer of the expectation on the fly.

**Even further step:**
When you have found a good way to estimate the expectation of the game, given the remaining cards in the shoe (and "basic "strategy"), which is fast enough, you may be able to implement a reinforcement learning algorithm for the money management.

... or you can stick with the simple plan: Positive expectation => High stakes. Negative expectation => Low stakes.

Good luck with your study,
-Øystein

Comment: Thank you for the well in-depth instructions. This is very helpful to me! The ironic part is I can do everything you mentioned with the deck, and have implemented, but just haven't got on the understanding of algorithms yet. That is what I'm doing now though.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a heuristic function that scores all possible moves an A.I. player can make.  This heuristic function takes in all available data that a player has access to, and the higher the score, the better the move.  It should take into account the probabilities of getting the specific card needed, vs. the dealer busting, etc.  Then the A.I. should simply pick the best move, i.e. the move with the maximum heuristic score.

Answer (score 0):

There are some systems for Blackjack (get around 49% for win). For ex.: http://www.docstoc.com/docs/79054261/Basic-Strategy-Chart---Easy-Money-Blackjack-System

So this is simple if {cards} then {action} algorithm

Answer (score 0):

In general you should not rely (primarily) on an imperative language to create your Blackjack player unless you are just going to focus on search as a primary (and probably only) strategy.  Instead please take a look at Clips (production rules) or Drools in order to quickly create a prototype.  There is an initial learning curve there.  Basically production rules, logic programming, neural nets and genetic algorithms are general purpose approaches that incorporate search in the execution or learning phase.  So why use these over just search? After all search algorithms are very powerful. Because production rules, logic programming, neural nets and genetic algorithms are more powerful than just applying a search algorithm and enable you to focus on your problem representation.

Another thing to consider is that in Blackjack you will want to incorporate probability as well (and maybe card counting!).